# How To Debug Magento Mystery Error on saveOrderAction() When All Debugging Is Enabled and No Error Message?

Tags: debugging

As title says all Magento debugging is enabled, and in php.ini all debugging is enabled, and mysql debugging is enabled. Error messages show fine in general. I can call for example a method that doesn't exist and it shows the error fine. The issue is: How do you debug an error when nothing is in the response and there is no error message?

I am clicking on place order on checkout and it just loads and then the button shows again, and looking in Chrome network to view the response, and there is none. I have tried debugging with xdebug following the execution, and on $this->getOnepage()->saveOrder() is where it seems like execution stops, but no error message or any clue as to why it doesn't work (like maybe a mysql integrity violation message).

Has this happened to any of you? How did you find the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very good way to debug when magento doesn't want to show the error messages. Go to:

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php

& add breakpoints in this function:

```
function mageCoreErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    if (strpos($errstr, 'DateTimeZone::__construct')!==false) {
        // there's no way to distinguish between caught system exceptions and warnings
        return false;
```

for some reason the error will never show to the page, but if in xdebug you add the breakpoints here it will show you the errors.